# How to hang a iMac 27 inch in wall with some space to connect my thunderbolt and USB?

Tags: mac, imac

I would like hang my iMac 27 inch Mid 2011 model in my living room due to spacing constraint. I recently come across VESA adapter to doing that as show int he video [www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D5_uMBMaCY](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D5_uMBMaCY) .The real problem is I couldn't connect my thunder bolt port for my time machine and other USB ports when the IMac is hanging now:( it is so close to the wall. Do you have any other options to wall hang it with minimal disturbance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

[image: Angled USB]

Google for "angled USB"

Comment: Sounds good to me. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately iMacs do not have VESA mount points. I would be very scared of mounting it to a wall. However, I would also be surprised if there is no "accessories" which would adapt the existing stand to a VESA compatable mount. If you want to mount to a wall, working with VESA mounts in some fashion is your best bet, there are tonnes of VESA wall mounts out there. If you find a way to adapt to VESA mounting points, a place to start for the rest of the mounting is monoprice.com , they have pretty good selection there.

Comment: Cheers let me try that for sure...